# Module has no attribute in Python

Tags: python, graphics

I am importing variables from a module, but it says that there is no instance of the variable that has been imported in. There are two files: eqparse and main. Ill include all the miscellaneous code (that likely isn't related) just in case. There are comments to help navigate the code.

The main code:

```
import graphics
import eqparse
# NOTE: For equation mapping, it will input a string and convert the data to a table. 
# After, you take in the table coords and map each point 


# dump vars here #
xypm = 0

counter = eqparse.counter

patternFind = eqparse.patternFind

indexlist = eqparse.indexlist

# profile initialization #
def init(name, nxsize, nysize, noffset, nzoom):
    global zoom
    zoom = nzoom
    global xsize
    xsize = nxsize
    global eqtype
    eqtype = bool(1)
    global ysize
    ysize = nysize
    global win
    win = GraphWin(name, nxsize, nysize)
    global offset
    offset = noffset
    global xymark
    xymark = (nzoom * -1)/2 
    global txsize
    txsize = nxsize/2
    global tysize
    tysize = nysize/2
    global txymark
    txymark = xymark * -1 + 1
    global xp1
    xp1 = Point(xypm,(txsize) + offset)
    global yp1
    yp1 = Point((tysize) + offset, xypm)
    global xp2
    xp2 = Point(xypm,(txsize) - offset)
    global yp2
    yp2 = Point((tysize) - offset, xypm)

# starting procedure #
def startUp():
        # xy lines #
    global xymark
    global xp1
    global xp2
    global yp1
    global yp2
    global xypm
    xtrace = Line(Point(0,tysize), Point(xsize,tysize))
    ytrace = Line(Point(txsize,0), Point(txsize,ysize))
    xtrace.draw(win)
    ytrace.draw(win)

        # grid drawer #
    while xymark < txymark:
        
        txline = Line(xp1, xp2)
        tyline = Line(yp1, yp2)
        txline.draw(win)
        tyline.draw(win)
        xypm = xypm + xsize/zoom
        xp1 = Point(xypm,(tysize) + offset)
        yp1 = Point((txsize) + offset, xypm)
        xp2 = Point(xypm,(tysize) - offset)
        yp2 = Point((txsize) - offset, xypm)
        xymark = xymark + 1

        # code for ending mark #
    Line(Point(txsize - offset, ysize - 1), Point(txsize + offset, ysize - 1)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(xsize - 1,tysize - offset), Point(xsize - 1, tysize + offset)).draw(win)

# point drawing #
def drawCo(nx, ny):
    pCircle = Circle(Point(xsize/zoom * (nx) + xsize/2, ysize - (ysize/zoom * (ny) + ysize/2)), 3)
    pCircle.setFill("black")
    pCircle.draw(win)


# main #
print("Checkpoint 1")
init("test",500, 500, 10, 20)
print("Checkpoint 2")
startUp()
print("Checkpoint 3")
drawCo(3,5)
print("Checkpoint 4")
patternFind("Dung","DungBeatlesbeingadungbeetle")
print("Checkpoint 5")
print(counter)
print("Checkpoint 6")
for x in range(len(indexlist)):
    print(indexlist[x])
print("Checkpoint 7")

# exit function #
win.getMouse()
win.close()
```

The eqparse code:

```
#   eqparse will look for certain patterns in strings, generate an equation,
#   and create a table that a drawing function can read


global indexlist

global counter

# convert string to valid equation data


def convStr(input):
    if input[0] == 'y':
        print("Linear")
        
    elif input[0] == 'r':
        print("Polar")
    else:
        print("Use Equation type on left side")

# subroutine that will be used to find patterns in a sequence #

def patternFind(pattern, input):

    indexlist = []
    
    counter = 0

    l = len(pattern)

    tstr =""

    if l > len(input):
        pass
    else:
        i = 0
        j = len(input) - len(pattern) + 1
        k=0
        while j > 0:
            tstr = ""
            i=0
            while len(tstr) < l:
                tstr = tstr + input[i + k]
                i = i + 1
            if tstr == pattern:
                counter = counter + 1
                indexlist.append(i+k)
            else: 
                pass
            j = j - 1
            k=k+1
```

The output/error code:

```
module 'eqparse' has no variable 'counter'
```

Help of any kind is appreciated.

I tried changing the variable name just in case it was already used in Python's standard library or the graphics library, but nothing changed.

Comment: define the variables as global within the function ``patternF` not outside.

Comment: I have the same result whether it is located outside or inside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a variable at the module level,
you're defining a *global* variable.
When you define a variable inside a function,
you're defining a *local* variable.
if you say `foo = 7` on the module level,
and then `foo = 17` in a function,
you are changing the *local* variable `foo`,
which is *unrelated* to the *global* variable `foo`,
however, if, before you say `foo = 17` in the function,
you say `global foo`, in the function,
then you are saying "when i define foo, i'm redefining the global variable foo".

```
#   eqparse will look for certain patterns in strings, generate an equation,
#   and create a table that a drawing function can read

indexlist = []
counter = 0


# convert string to valid equation data


def convStr(input):
    if input[0] == 'y':
        print("Linear")
        
    elif input[0] == 'r':
        print("Polar")
    else:
        print("Use Equation type on left side")

# subroutine that will be used to find patterns in a sequence #

def patternFind(pattern, input):
    global indexlist
    global counter

    l = len(pattern)

    tstr =""

    if l > len(input):
        pass
    else:
        i = 0
        j = len(input) - len(pattern) + 1
        k=0
        while j > 0:
            tstr = ""
            i=0
            while len(tstr) < l:
                tstr = tstr + input[i + k]
                i = i + 1
            if tstr == pattern:
                counter = counter + 1
                indexlist.append(i+k)
            else: 
                pass
            j = j - 1
            k=k+1
```

Comment: Very intuitive and in-depth description. Thank you for the help; this was of much service to me.

Comment: if you liked the answer, please accept it